# How to pass an encrypted text field into the body of a http call out in flow

Tags: visual-workflow, httppost, field-level-encryption

I have built a flow that makes a http callout - Method POST - to pass contact ID Verification documents to an external system.
I have a custom Object `Verification_Document__c` with a master-detail relationship to contact.

On the `Verification_Document__c` object there are several encrypted text fields to protect identifying numbers (such as a Passport number or Licence Number).

My flow GETs all of the Verification documents associated to a contact and then loops through the collection.

As it loops through, it assigns the relevant value to the apex defined variable for the POST request body.

The issue I am facing is that it throws an error when trying to assign the encrypted text value to the variable.

**Error:**

```
 The flow failed to access the value for 
 Loop_through_Verification_Documents.Aust_Passport_Number__c 
 because the data type Text (Encrypted) is unsupported.
```

Is there a way I can pass the encrypted value to the POST request body?

If not, can anyone else suggest a way to ensure I can make this data travel safely?

thanks in advance

Comment: Very similar to https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/414585/using-encrypted-field-in-lookup-with-apex

Comment: hi @identigral I did see that post before I put up mine, however they are referring to decrypting the field via Apex as they are trying to refer to the encrypted field in a lookup. That is not what I am trying to do - I just need to be able to put the field in the payload of a http callout.

Comment: The other Q&A is also a HTTP callout, the rest is unclear. The details of how your flow works and how it passes the info to a callout are important. Please edit your question and provide a [Minimal, Complete and Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).